# Angular JS + Typescript Controller As syntax Form Validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, typescript

I have an angular js (v1) app with typescript (Controller As syntax). I have forms in my views. I want to know how to validate forms values in an angular better way.

This is an example of a view:

```
<form novalidate name="vm.cvForm" class="cv-validation">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
        <input name="cvName" type="text" class="cv-resize-input" placeholder="_" ng-model="vm.formState.version" required/>
        <div ng-show="vm.cvForm.$submitted || vm.cvForm.cvName.$touched">
            <div ng-show="vm.cvForm.cvName.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-10 columns">
        <select
            name= "cvLang"
            ng-model="vm.formState.languageList[$index]"
            class="cv-resize-input select select-margin-left mouse-hover"
            ng-repeat="tmpLang in vm.formState.languageList track by $index"
            ng-options="lang as lang.name for lang in vm.langs track by lang.id"
            required>
            <option value="">{{"general.select" | translate}}</option>
        </select>
            <span ng-show="vm.cvForm.cvLang.$error.required">Select language.</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I don't hace an input submit, as my "accept button" is a directive used in more places.

The problem I have here is that "client side" validation actually is done (messages appears in the view), but anyway data are being inserted in my persistence layer. How can a avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: value of ng-model expression is not changed if validation has errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322690/angularjs-setpristine-with-typescript-form-is-undefined  Take a look there and see if that helps.